# Pods in a statefulset and headless service do not get the right dns records

Tags: kubernetes

**Information:**

- Kubernetes version: 1.14.1
- Cloud: Azure (not AKS)
- DNS: CoreDNS
- Deployer: Kubespray
- Container: containerd
- 3 worker nodes

**Description**

I have this statefulset:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: busy
spec:
  serviceName: busy
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: busy
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      name: busy
      labels:
        app: busy
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: busy
          image: busybox:1.28
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command:
            - sleep
            - "3600"
      restartPolicy: Always
```

And this headless service:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: busy-headless
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  selector:
    app: busy
```

The statefulset creates 3 pods (busy-{1,2,3}). According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id), each pod should have a DNS record like `busy-{1,2,3}.busy-headless.default.svc.cluster.local`.

**Issue**

When I try to resolve the DNS entries associated to the record `busy-headless.default.svc.cluster.local` from `busy-0` I get

```
17:00 $ kubectl exec -ti busy-0 -- nslookup busy-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.233.0.3
Address 1: 10.233.0.3 coredns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      busy-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.233.67.10 10-233-67-10.busy-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 2: 10.233.68.27 10-233-68-27.busy-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 3: 10.233.68.26 10-233-68-26.busy-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 4: 10.233.69.11 busy-0.busy.default.svc.cluster.local
```

From `busy-1` the command returns `busy-1.busy.default.svc.cluster.local` for `busy-1` and `10-233-69-11.busy-headless.default.svc.cluster.local` for `busy-0`.

A nslookup on `busy-{1,2,3}.busy-headless.default.svc.cluster.local` returns an error.

What could possibly be wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your StatefulSet manifest try to specify:

```
serviceName: busy-headless
```

Comment: Thank you, I miss that part of the conf!

Comment: + [The headless service must exist **before** the StatefulSet, and is responsible for the network identity of the set.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#statefulset-v1-apps)